# How do I remove borders and the scrollbar on a looping video background?

Tags: html, css

wanted to find a way to have a looping video background. which always fully covers the screen. It works how I want it to rn, but when I increased the vh and vw to 100% it added scroll bars and still has padding and a margin around the video.  How can I fix this?

```
<section class="container">

  <video class="fullscreen" src="comp1.mp4" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  </video>

<style media="screen">


  video.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);


  &::-webkit-media-controls {
     display:none !important;
  }
}

.container {
   position: relative;
   display: grid;
   place-items: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;

   background: #ccc;
}

.content {
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   place-items: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin: 0 to the body?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis ah thanks that fixed it in chrome. Just realised its still broken in ie :(

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PmJ8NKp its flush in chrome, but theres still a white area surrounding the whole page + some black on the sides of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default you browser gives padding/margin. You can try to remove it by giving margin and padding 0: `* { box-sizing:border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }` as to hiding scroll bar you can use `overflow : hidden`

Comment: Thanks! that works on chrome, and fixed the white border I get in internet explorer. But I still get black bars on the sides of the video. I want the video to cover the screen, even if some parts of the top/side isn't visible, as long as it stays centred. Any ideas?

Comment: Does video itself have black bars?

Comment: no, and in chrome there are no black bars, but there are when I open it in ie

Comment: Try to set 100% width and height to container. If it didn’t help try to use ‘ object-fit: cover;’ if still not give shout back :)

Comment: I gave it a go but sadly it didn't fix it, I'm wondering if I've done something which ie doesn't support but chrome does

Comment: Well IE doesn’t support much. Please try considering this code pen: [link](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/OVGWLG)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245019/discussion-between-blair-a-and-lance).

Answer (score 1):

add style to that tag

overflow:hidden

Comment: this answer was already provided??